# Zustand, persist, react native and react-native-mmkv-loader. How do I only update the changed values?

Tags: react-native, persist, zustand

I have the following code:

```
const contractStorage = new MMKVLoader().initialize()

export const useStore = create<StoreType>()(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      contracts: {},
      setContracts: (contract: Contract) => set((state) => ({ ...state, [contract.id]: contract })),
    }),
    {
      name: 'contract-storage',
      version: 0,
      getStorage: () => contractStorage,
    },
  ),
)
```

This accesses the methods defined on the MMKVLoader, one of which being setItem, which updates the entire instance

Is there a way to use the persist middleware to only update the specific key/value pair in the storage that has actually changed?

My current workaround is the following:

```
export const useStore = create<StoreType>()(
  (set) => ({
    contracts: {},
    setContracts: (contract: Contract) => set((state) => {
      contractStorage.setMap(contract.id, contract)
      return ({ ...state, [contract.id]: contract })
    }),
  })
)
```